# multiple JSON Data log and PUT to server

Tags: javascript, json

I have a javascript function which generates JSON data at every certain second and then PUT it to a cloud server. Now I don't want to POST in realtime, rather I want to log this data in a buffer and say after n number of data log I will PUT to cloud. For example I want to log 50 data point in 10 second and then with timestamp I will PUT to a server

Now JSON data is passed through var `fromDatan`. JSON data format is

```
{"value":"-2.1282838391939194"}
```

Now the code is:

```
var acc;
    var watchID = null;

function startWatch() {

            //set frequency of accelerometer update.1000 = 1 second

            var options = { frequency: 1000 };
            watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);

        }


    function stopWatch() {
            if (watchID) {
            navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
            }
        }


    //DISPLAY ACCELERATION DATA

    function onSuccess(acceleration) {
            acc = acceleration;
            var element = document.getElementById("accelerometer");
            element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x         + '<br />' +
                              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y         + '<br />' +
                              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z         + '<br />' +
                              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';

                datalock();


        }


function postdata () {
        var accx = acc.x;
        alert(accx);




            var fromDatan = JSON.stringify(fromData);
                alert(fromDatan);

                //POST JSON SENSOR DATA

                $.ajax({
                url: "http://abcd.com",
                headers: {
                    "X-API-KEY": "2b9asdedqedqxdqd7956e6f7a",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                type: "PUT",
                data: fromDatan,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                }
                });
                return false;

        //var fromData = {};
        }
        var fromData;
        var jsonCounter = 0;

        function datalock(){
            alert("Entering");
            fromData.push({
            value: accx.toString(),
            });

            jsonCounter++;

            // post only after 10 entries
            if (jsonCounter >= 10) {
            postdata ();
            jsonCounter = 0; // reset
            };

            //var fromData; // make it global as it is used in other function.
        }
```

But the code is not working now. Please let me know where the problem is. although all other things are correct, the pushing I couldn't implement properly. Can anyone please help me out? It is just hitting on "Entering alert . that's it .Not going to function `postdata()`

Comment: Is your code producing more than 9 counters?